# How to transfer values as string from class file to output file?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, user-interface, mfc

I am a beginner to programming, I have made a MFC based GUI application and linked the variables by Cptr to a  calculation class file. There are 3 class files Main Dialog, Calculation & Output. Now i need to print the outputs of that calculation class file to an output dialog.

I have made a Output dialog box along with its class & header file, but am unable to transfer the correct values from one class to another and the values are printed in the Output dialog box are 0.00 as they are initialized for the same.

Calculation cpp:

```
Output Dlg;
Dlg.m_hvmid1 = HV_Tmid_1;
Dlg.m_hvmid2 = HV_Tmid_2;
Dlg.m_hvmid3 = HV_Tmid_3;
Dlg.m_hvmid4 = HV_Tmid_4;
Dlg.m_lvmid1 = LV_Tmid_1;
Dlg.m_lvmid2 = LV_Tmid_2;
Dlg.m_lvmid3 = LV_Tmid_3;
Dlg.m_lvmid4 = LV_Tmid_4;
```

Output cpp:

```
Output::Output(CWnd* pParent /*=nullptr*/)
: CDialog(IDD_OUTPUT, pParent)
{

}

Output::~Output()
{

}

void Output::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_HV_MID1, m_d_hvmid1);
    DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_HV_MID2, m_d_hvmid2);
    DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_HV_MID3, m_d_hvmid3);
    DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_HV_MID4, m_d_hvmid4);
    DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_LV_MID1, m_d_lvmid1);
    DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_LV_MID2, m_d_lvmid2);
    DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_LV_MID3, m_d_lvmid3);
    DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_LV_MID4, m_d_lvmid4);

}


BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(Output, CDialog)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


// Output message handlers

BOOL Output::OnInitDialog()
{
    UpdateData();
    CDialog::OnInitDialog();
    AssignDlgToPtr1();

    return TRUE;  // return TRUE unless you set the focus to a control
    // EXCEPTION: OCX Property Pages should return FALSE
}

void Output::AssignDlgToPtr1()
{
    UpdateData();

        m_d_hvmid1.Format(_T("%f"), m_hvmid1);
        m_d_hvmid2.Format(_T("%f"), m_hvmid2);
        m_d_hvmid3.Format(_T("%f"), m_hvmid3);
        m_d_hvmid4.Format(_T("%f"), m_hvmid4);
        m_d_lvmid1.Format(_T("%f"), m_lvmid1);
        m_d_lvmid2.Format(_T("%f"), m_lvmid2);
        m_d_lvmid3.Format(_T("%f"), m_lvmid3);
        m_d_lvmid4.Format(_T("%f"), m_lvmid4);

    UpdateData(0);
}
```

Main Dialog Code:

```
void CThermalToolDlg::OnCalculate()
{
    UpdateData();
    if (!Validate()) return;
    AssignDlgToPtr();
    Cptr.OnCalculate();

    Output Dlg;
    Dlg.DoModal();

    UpdateData(FALSE);
}
```

Can someone point me in the correct direction to display correct calculated results instead of initial results? I think I've got the order wrong.

Comment: Where is `Cptr` defined?

Comment: Cptr is declared in MainDlg header.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle I also assigned the calculated values to a newly defined set of variables by Dlg.variable = calculated variable. It shows the correct value in Calculation cpp but as soon as it jumps to Output cpp, its value becomes zero. I tried transferring Calculated value, string value and now directly the output variable, but still the value is not transferred.

Comment: But you are not showing us all the code so it is hard to help you. Please show us sufficient code. Also have you tried debugging your project and stepping through it to see when it goes wrong?

Comment: @AndrewTruckle I have now shown the more code. In debugging the code, when the breakpoint jumps from Calculation class to output class the values become zero. Also any when converted to static value it gives debugging error in obj file, hence that option is out of the question.

Comment: Thanks. But these are still only bits of code. We are not seeing it in context. For example, we don't know what `Cptr.OnCalculate();` does. Without seeing the whole thing we don't really know what you are doing. That said, you seem to have two `Dlg` variables. So one is populated the the other is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically the solution was quite simple. Cptr is an object which was called in two classes. Instead I tried

```
void CThermalToolDlg::OnCalculate()
{
    UpdateData();
    if (!Validate()) return;
    AssignDlgToPtr();
    Cptr.OnCalculate();

    Output Dlg;

    Dlg.m_hvmid1 = Cptr.HV_Tmid_1;
    Dlg.m_hvmid2 = Cptr.HV_Tmid_2;
    Dlg.m_hvmid3 = Cptr.HV_Tmid_3;
    Dlg.m_hvmid4 = Cptr.HV_Tmid_4;
    Dlg.m_lvmid1 = Cptr.LV_Tmid_1;
    Dlg.m_lvmid2 = Cptr.LV_Tmid_2;
    Dlg.m_lvmid3 = Cptr.LV_Tmid_3;
    Dlg.m_lvmid4 = Cptr.LV_Tmid_4;
    Dlg.m_amb = Cptr.m_tamb;

    Dlg.DoModal();

    UpdateData(FALSE);
}
```

Cptr was not declared again in Output header. That was the only mistake